# Can this system of trigonometric equations be solved? How to solve it?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

Given an odd integer number n, and x is an unknown odd integer number and $ 1 < x \leq n $

Can i solve the following system of equations to find $x$? If i can, how to solve it?:

$$\begin{cases} y = {\Large \frac{-\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}x)}{\log(x)}}  \\ y = -\cos({\large \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{n}{x}}) \\ y = 0 \end{cases}$$

i only need 1 value for $x$, the lowest one.

You can use $n = 15$, for example. Solving this system of equations is very useful for number theory. And if it's easy, it's better. You can see it on http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiItY29zKHBpLzIqeCkvbG9nKHgpIiwiY29sb3IiOiIjRkYwMDAwIn0seyJ0eXBlIjowLCJlcSI6Ii1jb3MocGkvMioxNS94KSIsImNvbG9yIjoiIzAwRkYwMCJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiIwIiwiY29sb3IiOiIjMDAwMEZGIn0seyJ0eXBlIjoxMDAwfV0-

Solving this problem, is part of an algorithm.

I could not go further.

Comment: Since you're assuming $x$ is an odd integer bigger than $1$, we know that $\cos(\frac\pi{2}x)=0$, and that $\log(x)$ is positive (so there's no issue with a zero denominator); thus, the first equation reduces to $y=0$, giving no information that the last one doesn't already tell us. Consequently, the "system" amounts to nothing more than the middle equation with the substituted $y$ value: $$0 = \cos\left(\frac\pi{2}\frac{n}{x}\right)$$ Here, we see that we only need $\frac{n}{x}$ to be an odd integer; it will be, if and only if $x$ is a *divisor* of the odd integer $n$.

Comment: I will try everything they you tell me. Wait me for a while.

Answer (score 0):

If $y=0$ then you have to solve the equation $$0=-\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2x}\right)$$ so you will get
$$\frac{n \pi}{2x}=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$$

Comment: I didn't remember how these types of problems are solved. Thanks I'll try it. Wait for me for a while. If you are interested, then i can show you the algorithm.